# django-ratelimit stack keys. Not the intended behaviour

Tags: python, django, rate-limiting

I think my understanding of django-ratelimit is incorrect. I am using v3.0.0 but v2.0 produces the same results.
Lets say I have this code:

```
@ratelimit(key='post:username', rate='5/h', block=True)
@ratelimit(key='post:tenant', rate='5/h', block=True)
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    print(request.POST["username"])
    print(request.POST["tenant"])
    print("")
    return HttpResponse('hallo', content_type='text/plain', status=200)
```

Let's say tenant A submits username "Antwon" 6 times, then tenant A will be blocked for 1 hour, which is good. But, lets say tenant B also has a user "Antwon", then that user for tenant B will not be able to log in.
I would assume that Antwon for tenant B should still be able to log in, otherwise tenant A can DOS other tenants?

Is this intended behavior or is my implementation incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is incorrect. Here is a response from the creator of django-ratelimit:

Hi there! I think there might be some confusion about how multiple ratelimits interact, and how the cache keys get set/rotated.

> Multiple limits are ORed together—that is, if you fail any of them,
> you fail—but order matters. In this case, the outer limit,
> post:username, is tested first, then the tenant is tested. If the user
> succeeds, it counts as an attempt, regardless of what happens later.
> That's why the user keeps accruing attempts. If you want tenant to
> count first, you could re-order the decorators. However...
>
> If you want a single limit to the (username, tenant) pair, you could
> combine the two fields with custom logic, by creating a callable key
> that returned some combination of tenant and username (maybe
> {tenant}\u04{username} or hash them together).
>
> In terms of locking out tenants, there are a couple of things:
>
> First, ratelimit uses a staggered fixed-window strategy, instead of a
> sliding windows. So based on the rate, the period, the key value, and
> the group, there'll be some calculated window. For example, for 1
> hour, 11:03:29 will be the reset time, and the next reset time for
> that same combination will be 12:03:29, then 13:03:29, etc... The
> downside is that you if you had a limit of 100/h, you could do 200
> requests in a short span around the reset point. The upsides are that
> the calculation is share-nothing and can be done independently, the
> window reset even if you accidentally try again a little too early.
>
> Second, yes if you're doing hard blocks on user-supplied data like
> username (instead of e.g. using the authenticated user) it creates a
> denial-of-service vector. Where possible, another option is to use
> block=False, and do something like require a captcha rather than fully
> blocking.